# Use substring to keep previous and next index of a string without using array in Java

Tags: java, substring

I have a string which look like this (all substring are separate by return \n:

String myString = "1|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" +
"2|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" +
...etc
In my assignment I can't use arrays or other classes than String and System.

I need to delete a substring from that string by using substring method.

I use the Scanner to get the id from the user and after I have to compare that id to the id in my string which can be from 1 to 999. Then I have to keep all substrings except the one that has the same id as the user input.
To do that I need to use substring method to substring all characters from previous index and all characters of next index.

I want to keep all characters except the ones that are located between the id that's equals to the id entered by user and the "\n" witch is the end character of the present index.

That means that if my string is composed like this :

```
String myString = "1|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" +
                  "2|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
                  "3|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n";
```

If the user entered 2 as id, I need to substring the previous index "1|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" and the next "3|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n"; and assign that new string to a variable.

I have a method to retrieve the id from the string which is :

```
public static String getIdContact (String contact) {
        int i = 0;
        String id = "";
        while(contact.charAt(i) != '|') {
            Id+= contact.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
       return id;
}
```

I made another method to reach next index :

```
public static int nextIndex(int index, String carnet) {
   return carnet.indexOf("\n", index)+1;
}
```

and another method to extract a substring from the string :

```
public static String extractSubstring(String myString, char start, char end) {
        int indexStart;
        int indexEnd;
        String subString = null;
        if (myString != null) {
            indexStart = myString.indexOf(start);
            if (indexStart != -1) {
                indexEnd = myString.indexOf(end, indexStart + 1);
                if (indexEnd != -1) {
                    subString = myString.substring(indexStart + 1, indexEnd);
                }
            }
        }
        return subString;
    }
```

Finally, I have the main method that delete the substring from the string where I called the method to compare the given id from user to the id in the string.

```
public static String deleteContactFromMyString (String idContact, String myString) {
        String myNewString = "";
        String id = getIdContact(myString);

        *Here I have to compare the id given in parameter (id entered by user) to the id 
         returned from the getIdContact method (id in string)*

        *If both ids are equals, I need to substring all characters before that id and all characters after the "\n" and return the new string in the variable called myNewString*
         
        
         return myNewString;
        }
```

I'm confused and I don't know how to proceed to do that substring. Usually I will do that using an array but in my assignment it's not allowed to use them.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you make the task more complicated than necessary. Find the initial index of your "to deleting" substring by searching for `id+"|"` using the method `String.indexOf` and call it for example `start`. If this is positive find the next line separator (`"\n"`) after the found id and determine the end index of your "to deleting" substring and call it for example `end`. Determine your end result by concatenating the substring from your original string from `0 to start` and from `end` to end of your original string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String myString = "1|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" +
                      "2|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
                      "3|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n";
    int id = 2;
    int start = myString.indexOf(id+"|");
    if(start >= 0){
       int end = myString.indexOf("\n", start) + 1;
       String modified = myString.substring(0, start) + myString.substring(end);
       System.out.println(modified);
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("id not found");
    }
}
```